# Cannot resolve symbol 'notnull'

Tags: c#, resharper, .net-core-3.0

I'm using a `netcoreapp3.0` with `Visual Studio 16.3.1` and have a simple class. The `ReSharper 2019.2.20190828.152259` is also installed.

[image]

Here are the contents of the csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried removing the bin & obj folders, restarted Visual Studio, restarted Windows, but nothing helped.

Update: The problem comes from the ReSharper, but the latest update does not fix this. Is it perhaps a configuration problem?

Comment: Tried to reproduce using the same VS version but no ReSharper, and could not. Given that `notnull` is highlighted in red (which is something that VS would not do), and that the error is not in the Error List, I think this is a ReSharper issue. Try disabling it.

Comment: The problem does come from ReSharper, you are correct. Unfortunately, I need it for my work and the latest update does not fix this. I will update the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the support of JetBrains and they informed me that it is a missing feature, coming in the `2019.3` version.

Here is the issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-475665